Create column based on a rolling condition
I have a column called Entry signal that signals a Short Sell Entry but want to implement a backtest with stop loss at 15% that references the most recent last "Entry" from Entry Signal calling (if price rises more than 15% from Entry Price then exit trade, do nothing until next Entry and repeat).
I want to create below Stop Loss column
e.g.
Date       Price    Entry Signal   Stop Loss
2024-01-18  3595.0  NaN            NaN
2024-01-19  3280.0  Entry          NaN
2024-01-22  3505.0  NaN            NaN
2024-01-23  3945.0  NaN            Exit  (since first time price change triggers > +15%)
2024-01-24  4075.0  NaN            NaN
2024-03-07  10270.0 Entry          NaN
2024-03-08  8120.0  NaN            NaN
2024-03-11  14020.0  NaN           Exit

So far I can only think of for looping across each row but there must be a better way given I am working with a dataframe.

You could get the latest Entry with where+ffill, then filter the values above +15% and get the first with groupby.idxmax :
# identify entries
m = df['Entry Signal'].eq('Entry')

# identify prices with a 15% increase since last entry
s = df['Price'].div(df['Price'].where(m).ffill()).gt(1.15)

# get first one per group
df.loc[s[s].groupby(m.cumsum()).idxmax(), 'Stop Loss'] = 'Exit'

Output:
         Date    Price Entry Signal Stop Loss
0  2024-01-18   3595.0          NaN       NaN
1  2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry       NaN
2  2024-01-22   3505.0          NaN       NaN
3  2024-01-23   3945.0          NaN      Exit
4  2024-01-24   4075.0          NaN       NaN
5  2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry       NaN
6  2024-03-08   8120.0          NaN       NaN
7  2024-03-11  14020.0          NaN      Exit

Intermediates:
         Date    Price Entry Signal Stop Loss      m  where(m)    ffill       div  gt(1.15)
0  2024-01-18   3595.0          NaN       NaN  False       NaN      NaN       NaN     False
1  2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry       NaN   True    3280.0   3280.0  1.000000     False
2  2024-01-22   3505.0          NaN       NaN  False       NaN   3280.0  1.068598     False
3  2024-01-23   3945.0          NaN      Exit  False       NaN   3280.0  1.202744      True
4  2024-01-24   4075.0          NaN       NaN  False       NaN   3280.0  1.242378      True
5  2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry       NaN   True   10270.0  10270.0  1.000000     False
6  2024-03-08   8120.0          NaN       NaN  False       NaN  10270.0  0.790652     False
7  2024-03-11  14020.0          NaN      Exit  False       NaN  10270.0  1.365141      True


This is definitely in the right direction for what I want. However, line 4 (4  2024-01-24) should be false because there hasn't been a new entry yet after the Stop loss (cant have a new stop if no existing entry)... do you know how your code can account for that?

@Anonymous as you can see, my code is already doing that. This is guaranteed since idxmax only returns a single value.

Ah! I a blind I only looked at the boolean values in gt column. Thank you so much!

@Anonymous no worries, I recommend to also test this other approach as it might be faster (you have to test it with your real data)

A loop is not necessarily a bad approach if you compile your code with numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_exits(price, entry):
    ref = np.inf
    keep = False
    for i, (p, e) in enumerate(zip(price, entry)):
        if e:
            ref = p
            keep = True
        elif keep:
            if p/ref > 1.15:
                yield i
                keep = False

idx = list(get_exits(df['Price'].to_numpy(),
                     df['Entry Signal'].eq('Entry').to_numpy()))
# [3, 7]

df.loc[idx, 'Stop Loss'] = 'Exit'

NB. I'm assuming a range index here, if not replace idx by df.index[idx].
Output:
         Date    Price Entry Signal Stop Loss
0  2024-01-18   3595.0          NaN       NaN
1  2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry       NaN
2  2024-01-22   3505.0          NaN       NaN
3  2024-01-23   3945.0          NaN      Exit
4  2024-01-24   4075.0          NaN       NaN
5  2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry       NaN
6  2024-03-08   8120.0          NaN       NaN
7  2024-03-11  14020.0          NaN      Exit

timings
On 80k rows:
# numba
5.67 ms ± 253 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# pandas vectorial code
6.57 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

On 8M rows:
# numba
561 ms ± 39.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# pandas vectorial code
812 ms ± 117 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['1990-01-18', '1990-01-19', '1990-01-22', '1990-01-23', 
                            '1990-01-24', '1990-03-07', '1990-03-08', '1990-03-11']),
    'Price': [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 800.0],
    'Entry_Signal': ['NaN', 'Entry', 'NaN', 'Exit', 'NaN', 'Entry', 'NaN', 'Exit']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
# Calculate 10% Stop_Loss buffer based on Entry Price
df['Stop_Loss'] = np.where(df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Entry', df['Price'] * 1.10, np.nan)

# Forward fill Stop_Loss based on most recent Entry
df['Stop_Loss'] = df['Stop_Loss'].ffill()

# Handle Exit signal by setting Stop_Loss to NaN
df.loc[df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Exit', 'Stop_Loss'] = np.nan
# Identify exit and entry indices
exit_indices = df.index[df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Exit'].to_numpy()
entry_indices = df.index[df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Entry'].to_numpy()
next_entry_indices = np.searchsorted(entry_indices, exit_indices, side='right')


for exit_idx in exit_indices :
    
    m1 = (df.index > exit_idx)
    m2 = (df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Entry')
    # Find the next Entry after the current Exit
    next_entry_idx = df.index[(m1 & m2)].min()
    
    if pd.isna(next_entry_idx):
     #if no next Entry, set Stop_Loss to NaN for all remaining rows
     df.loc[exit_idx +1 :, 'Stop_Loss'] = np.nan
    
    else:
        #here we deal for the space between Exit and next Entry
        # set Stop_Loss to NaN for the segment between Exit and the next Entry
     df.loc[exit_idx +1 : next_entry_idx -1,'Stop_Loss'] = np.nan  
   
    
print(df)    
'''    
      Date  Price Entry_Signal  Stop_Loss
0 1990-01-18  100.0          NaN        NaN
1 1990-01-19  200.0        Entry      220.0
2 1990-01-22  300.0          NaN      220.0
3 1990-01-23  400.0         Exit        NaN
4 1990-01-24  500.0          NaN        NaN
5 1990-03-07  600.0        Entry      660.0
6 1990-03-08  700.0          NaN      660.0
7 1990-03-11  800.0         Exit        NaN

'''

Also more efficiently create a mask
# Create a boolean mask for resetting Stop_Loss after each Exit
reset_mask = pd.Series(False, index=df.index)

# Use vectorized operations to build the reset mask
for exit_idx in exit_indices:
    # Find the next entry index after the current exit
    m1 = (df.index > exit_idx)
    m2 = (df['Entry_Signal'] == 'Entry')
    next_entry_idx = df.index[m1 & m2].min()
    if pd.isna(next_entry_idx):
        reset_mask[exit_idx :] = True
    else:
        reset_mask[exit_idx :next_entry_idx] = True

# Apply the reset mask to Stop_Loss column
df.loc[reset_mask, 'Stop_Loss'] = np.nan

